# Scrollable Frame() inside Text() in tkinter

Tags: text, scroll, tkinter, frame

I've embedded 100 rows in 2 columns. Each row is inside a single frame, and all packed inside a text widget. I'm trying to add a scroll bar, but it scrolls only text, while the columns won't move.

```
    frame_fields = tk.Text(self.window)
    frame_fields.pack_propagate(0)
    tf = {}
    text_labels = tk.Text(frame_fields)
    text_labels.pack(side='left', expand='yes', fill='both')

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame_fields)
    scrollbar.config(command=text_labels.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    text_labels.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    for f in range(100):
        tf[f] = tk.Frame(text_labels)
        e_find = tk.Entry(tf[f])
        e_replace = tk.Entry(tf[f])
        e_find.pack(side='left')
        e_replace.pack(side='left')
        tf[f].pack()
    frame_fields.pack()
```

How should I change this code, so `text_labels` scroll?

### A Solution

[image]

The code below creates the scrollable cells:

```
def create_cells(self):
    """Create cells for exception text"""
    # ----------------------------------------------
    frame_fieldsscroll = tk.Text(self.main, relief='flat')
    text_fields = tk.Text(frame_fieldsscroll, relief='flat')
    frame_fieldsscroll.window_create('insert', window=text_fields)

    tf = {}
    for f in range(31):

        e_find = tk.Entry(text_fields, width=16, relief='flat')
        e_replace = tk.Entry(text_fields, width=16, relief='flat')

        e_find.insert(0, 'find'+str(f))
        e_replace.insert(0, 'replace'+str(f))

        e_find.grid(row=0, column=0)
        e_replace.grid(row=0, column=1)

        text_fields.window_create('insert', window=e_find)
        text_fields.window_create('insert', window=e_replace)

        text_fields.insert('end', '\n')

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame_fieldsscroll, width=15)
    scrollbar.config(command=text_fields.yview)
    text_fields.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    frame_fieldsscroll.pack()
    scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    text_fields.pack(fill='both')

    text_fields.configure(state='disabled')
    frame_fieldsscroll.configure(state='disabled')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For objects in a window to be scrollable along with the text you must add them with the [window_create](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.window_create-method) method of the text widget instead of using `pack` or `grid` or `place`.

Comment: So, that was the missing piece... Thanks. I'll implement it and update the code.