# Module Object has no Attribute Listbox - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

I am trying to create a scrollbar on buttonclick. Below is my code:

```
            username = StringVar()

            self.uentry1=ttk.Entry(self.frame1,textvariable=username)
            self.uentry1.pack()
            self.ubutton=ttk.Button(self.frame1,text="NAME!",command=self.get_user_info)
            self.ubutton.pack()

    def get_user_info(self):

            self.uscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame1)
            self.uscrollbar.pack(fill='both',expand=1)

            self.ulist = ttk.Listbox(self.page5,yscrollcommand=self.uscrollbar.set)
            self.ulist.pack(side=LEFT,fill='both')
            self.uscrollbar.config(command=ulist.yview)

            self.ubutton1 = ttk.Button(self.frame1,text = "PID's",width = 10)
            self.ubutton1.grid()
```

This throws the error `Module Object has no Attribute Listbox`. Please point out where I am going wrong.(the above code is incomplete as I need to clear this to go further)

Comment: Please post full code. I need it to answer.

Comment: @JonahFleming : Added my code above. I can see a listbox kinda thing with a scrollbar in the middle. I want it to be like the image here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302504/scrollable-frame-inside-text-in-tkinter

Comment: Go [here](http://pythonqanda.weebly.com) to contact me more. I will research all of your questions thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error is telling you, the ttk module has no attribute named `Listbox`. `Listbox` is part of the tkinter (or Tkinter) package.